# Online PPO: TensorFlow Session returns NaN

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm trying to train an online Proximal Policy Optimization model using tensorflow but after a while, the tensorflow session starts returning NaNs. This causes my agent to `step` using those nans and eventually the whole thing becomes a mess.

**Short snippet from console:**

```sh
Action Taken   [2.        1.3305835 0.9937418]
Observation    [  0.69689728  -0.46114012 -11.39961704  -0.05004346  -0.05004346
   0.74720544   3.49857114   3.05071477  -1.10276782  -9.71530186]
Reward Gained  -0.023699851569145534

Action Taken   [2.         0.62562937 1.0081608 ]
Observation    [ 0.71591491 -0.47488649 11.84026042 -0.05004346 -0.05004346  0.75886336
  3.49857114  3.07180685 -1.12458586 -9.84382414]
Reward Gained  -0.015462812448075767

Action Taken   [nan nan nan]
Observation    [        nan         nan         nan -0.05004346 -0.05004346         nan
         nan         nan         nan         nan]
Reward Gained  nan

Action Taken   [nan nan nan]
Observation    [        nan         nan         nan -0.05004346 -0.05004346         nan
         nan         nan         nan         nan]
Reward Gained  nan
```

**My code [UPDATED]:**

```py
import gym
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import rocket_lander_gym

EP_LEN = 200
GAMMA = 0.9
SL_LR = 1e-4
CR_LR = 1e-4
BATCH = 5
ACTOR_UPDATE_STEPS = 20
CRITIC_UPDATE_STEPS = 20
STATE_DIM, ACT_DIM = 10, 3

METHOD = [
    dict(name='kl_penalty', kl_target=0.01, lam=0.5),   
    dict(name='clip', epsilon=0.2),
][1]

PRINT_DEBUG_MSG = True

class PPO:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tfsess = tf.Session()
        self.tf_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, STATE_DIM], 'state')

        # Critic (value network)
        with tf.variable_scope('critic'):
            # Layers
            l1 = tf.layers.dense(self.tf_state, 100, tf.nn.relu)
            # Value
            self.value = tf.layers.dense(l1, 1)
            # Discounted reward: reward in the furture
            self.tf_dreward = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], 'discounted_reward')
            # Advantage: determine quality of action
            self.advantage = self.tf_dreward - self.value
            # Loss function: minimize the advantage over time
            # The loss function is a mean squared error
            self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.advantage))
            # Gradient descent using Adam optimizer
            self.train_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(CR_LR)
            gradients, variables = zip(*self.train_opt.compute_gradients(self.loss))
            gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, 1.0)
            self.train_opt = self.train_opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))

        # Actor (policy network)
        pi, pi_params = self.tinynn('pi', trainable=True)
        old_pi, old_pi_params = self.tinynn('old_pi', trainable=False)

        # Sample actions from both the old and the new policy networks
        with tf.variable_scope('sample_action'):
            # Choose an action from the distribution learnt
            self.sample_operation = tf.squeeze(pi.sample(1), axis=0)
        with tf.variable_scope('update_old_pi'):
            # Choose an action from the distribution learnt
            self.update_old_pi_operation = [old_pi.assign(p) for p, old_pi in zip(pi_params, old_pi_params)]

        # Placeholder for the action and the advantage
        self.tf_action = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, ACT_DIM], 'action')
        self.tf_advantage = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], 'advantage')

        # Compute loss function
        with tf.variable_scope('loss'):
            with tf.variable_scope('surrogate'):
                ratio = pi.prob(self.tf_advantage) / old_pi.prob(self.tf_advantage)
                surrogate = ratio * self.tf_advantage

            # KL penalty
            if METHOD['name'] == 'kl_penalty':
                # Lambda
                self.tf_lambda = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, None, 'lambda')
                # Compute KL divergence between old and new policy
                kl = tf.contrib.distributions.kl_divergence(old_pi, pi)
                # Get mean
                self.kl_mean = tf.reduce_mean(kl)
                # Compute loss using surrogate
                self.aloss = -(tf.reduce_mean(surrogate - self.tf_lambda * kl))
            else:
                self.aloss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.minimum(surrogate, tf.clip_by_value(ratio, 1.-METHOD['epsilon'],  1.+METHOD['epsilon']) * self.tf_advantage))

        # Minimize the loss using gradient descent
        with tf.variable_scope('atrain'):
            self.atrain_operation = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(SL_LR)
            gradients, variables = zip(*self.atrain_operation.compute_gradients(self.aloss))
            gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, 1.0)
            self.atrain_operation = self.atrain_operation.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))

        # Write to disk
        tf.summary.FileWriter("log/", self.tfsess.graph)

        # Run the session
        self.tfsess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


    def update(self, state, action, reward):
        self.tfsess.run(self.update_old_pi_operation)
        advantage = self.tfsess.run(self.advantage, {self.tf_state: state, self.tf_dreward: reward})

        # Update actor (policy)
        if METHOD['name'] == 'kl_penalty':
            for _ in range(ACTOR_UPDATE_STEPS):
                _, kl = self.tfsess.run([self.atrain_operation, self.kl_mean], {self.tf_state: state, self.tf_action: action, tf_advantage: advantage, self.tf_lambda: METHOD['lam']})
                if kl > 4*METHOD['kl_target']:
                    break
            if kl < METHOD['kl_target'] / 1.5:
                # Adaptive lambda
                METHOD['lam'] /= 2
            elif kl > METHOD['kl_target'] * 1.5:
                METHOD['lam'] *= 2
            # Lambda might explode, we need to clip it
            METHOD['lam'] = np.clip(METHOD['lam'], 1e-4, 10)
        else:
            [self.tfsess.run(self.atrain_operation, {self.tf_state: state, self.tf_action: action, self.tf_advantage: advantage}) for _ in range(ACTOR_UPDATE_STEPS)]

        # Update critic (value)
        [self.tfsess.run(self.train_opt, {self.tf_state: state, self.tf_dreward: reward}) for _ in range(CRITIC_UPDATE_STEPS)]


    def tinynn(self, name, trainable):
        with tf.variable_scope(name):
            l1 = tf.layers.dense(self.tf_state, 100, tf.nn.relu, trainable=trainable)
            mu = 2 * tf.layers.dense(l1, ACT_DIM, tf.nn.tanh, trainable=trainable)
            sigma = tf.layers.dense(l1, ACT_DIM, tf.nn.softplus, trainable=trainable)
            norm_dist = tf.distributions.Normal(loc=mu, scale=sigma)
        params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope=name)
        return norm_dist, params


    def choose_action(self, state):
        state = state[np.newaxis, :]
        action = self.tfsess.run(self.sample_operation, {self.tf_state: state})[0]
        return np.clip(action, -1, 1)


    def get_value(self, state):
        if state.ndim < 2: state = state[np.newaxis, :]
        return self.tfsess.run(self.value, {self.tf_state: state})[0, 0]


    def train(self, env, ppo, epochs, render=True):
        # Rewards
        all_ep_r = []
        # Training loop
        for ep in range(epochs):
            # Initial state
            s = env.reset()
            # States, actions and rewards
            buffer_s, buffer_a, buffer_r = [], [], []
            # Initial reward
            ep_r = 0
            # For a single episode
            for t in range(EP_LEN):
                if render:
                    # Render the environment
                    env.render()
                # Choose best action
                a = ppo.choose_action(s)
                # State,reward,done,info
                s_, r, done, _ = env.step(a)
                if PRINT_DEBUG_MSG:
                    print("Action Taken  ",a)
                    print("Observation   ",s_)
                    print("Reward Gained ",r, end='\n\n')
                # Add to buffers
                buffer_s.append(s)
                buffer_a.append(a)
                buffer_r.append((r+8)/8)    # normalize reward, find to be useful
                s = s_
                # Total reward
                ep_r += r

                # Update PPO
                if (t+1) % BATCH == 0 or t == EP_LEN - 1:
                    # Get value
                    v_s_ = ppo.get_value(s_)
                    # Discounted reward
                    discounted_r = []
                    # Update rewards
                    for r in buffer_r[::-1]:
                        v_s_ = r + GAMMA * v_s_
                        discounted_r.append(v_s_)
                    discounted_r.reverse()
                    # Buffer states actions rewards
                    bs, ba, br = np.vstack(buffer_s), np.vstack(buffer_a), np.array(discounted_r)[:, np.newaxis]
                    buffer_s, buffer_a, buffer_r = [], [], []
                    ppo.update(bs, ba, br)

                # Check if done
                if done:
                    print("Simulation done.")
                    break
            # Append episode rewards
            if ep == 0: all_ep_r.append(ep_r)
            else: all_ep_r.append(all_ep_r[-1]*0.9 + ep_r*0.1)
            # Close the environment
            env.close()
        # Return all episode rewards
        return all_ep_r


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ppo = PPO()
    env = gym.make('RocketLander-v0')
    reward = ppo.train(env, ppo, 100)
    print(reward)
```

**What I have tried:**

1. I have tried lowering the learning rate of both my actor and critic    networks but the nans are still there.
2. Reduced the `BATCH` number so that the PPO gets updated faster.

I have been stuck with this problem for hours now, I can't find any solutions online. I'm also a newbie, if there are any dumb mistakes, please pardon me.

**UPDATE: TRACEBACK**

```sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1334, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1319, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1407, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Found Inf or NaN global norm. : Tensor had NaN values
     [[{{node atrain/VerifyFinite/CheckNumerics}} = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="Found Inf or NaN global norm.", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](atrain/global_norm/global_norm)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 209, in <module>
    reward = ppo.train(env, ppo, 100)
  File "main.py", line 191, in train
    ppo.update(bs, ba, br)
  File "main.py", line 118, in update
    [self.tfsess.run(self.atrain_operation, {self.tf_state: state, self.tf_action: action, self.tf_advantage: advantage}) for _ in range(ACTOR_UPDATE_STEPS)]
  File "main.py", line 118, in <listcomp>
    [self.tfsess.run(self.atrain_operation, {self.tf_state: state, self.tf_action: action, self.tf_advantage: advantage}) for _ in range(ACTOR_UPDATE_STEPS)]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1152, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1328, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1348, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Found Inf or NaN global norm. : Tensor had NaN values
     [[node atrain/VerifyFinite/CheckNumerics (defined at main.py:90)  = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="Found Inf or NaN global norm.", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](atrain/global_norm/global_norm)]]

Caused by op 'atrain/VerifyFinite/CheckNumerics', defined at:
  File "main.py", line 207, in <module>
    ppo = PPO()
  File "main.py", line 90, in __init__
    gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, 1.0)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/clip_ops.py", line 265, in clip_by_global_norm
    "Found Inf or NaN global norm.")
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/numerics.py", line 47, in verify_tensor_all_finite
    verify_input = array_ops.check_numerics(t, message=msg)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 817, in check_numerics
    "CheckNumerics", tensor=tensor, message=message, name=name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 488, in new_func
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3274, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1770, in __init__
    self._traceback = tf_stack.extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Found Inf or NaN global norm. : Tensor had NaN values
     [[node atrain/VerifyFinite/CheckNumerics (defined at main.py:90)  = CheckNumerics[T=DT_FLOAT, message="Found Inf or NaN global norm.", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](atrain/global_norm/global_norm)]]
```

Comment: tried your network on more simpler environments? Like continuousaction mountain car.

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan Nope but it should technically work. The code provided here is actually a slightly modified version of the code found in this video: https://youtu.be/09OMoGqHexQ and https://github.com/MorvanZhou/Reinforcement-learning-with-tensorflow/blob/master/contents/12_Proximal_Policy_Optimization/simply_PPO.py

Comment: I encourage you to try the simpler domains first to verify if the code is fine, or it's a domain dependent issue.

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan I just tried it out with MountainCarContinuous-v0, it works for a few episodes and then I have the same problem (NaNs being returned by the model).

Comment: try clipping the gradients before applying. check if gradients explode.

Comment: @SridharThiagarajan I tried clipping the gradient, it ran for about 2 seconds and I get this error: `Found Inf or NaN global norm. : Tensor had NaN values`. Please see the update above for the complete traceback.

Answer (score 4):

### Investigation:

For the sake of simplicity, I modify your code to run with Pendulum-v0 instead of the custom environment RocketLander-v0 on Google Colab.

The following are the modifications I made to run Pendulum-v0:

Remove the line: `import rocket_lander_gym`

Change the line: `STATE_DIM, ACT_DIM = 10, 3` to this: `STATE_DIM, ACT_DIM = 3, 1`

Change the line: `env = gym.make('RocketLander-v0')` to this: `env = gym.make('Pendulum-v0')`

After making these slight but necessary modifications to run Pendulum-v0, your code is still producing nans in the final `print(reward)` statement. This hints that the problem most likely lies with the code & it's unlikely a game environment issue.

The output for final `print(reward)` statement **before** fixing the problems (contains nans all the way to the end of the output):

```
[-1239.414496251207, -1267.7001978172505, -1247.1635071416315, -1255.8660458301786, -1246.770645397439, -1259.1171723968932, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

### Solution:

After a closer examination, I found the following problems & made some changes to your code which eventually solves the nans issue.

(The **actual** problems that cause the nans are in **point 5 & 6**. The magic number `2`, which is the multiplier you used for multiplying `mu` is different from the upper bound of your clip `1` in **point 6.**)

**1)** Your probability ratio is wrong so I change it from this:

`ratio = pi.prob(self.tf_advantage) / old_pi.prob(self.tf_advantage)`

to this:

`ratio = pi.prob(self.tf_action) / old_pi.prob(self.tf_action)`

**2)** You have 2 `self.train_opt`

```
self.train_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(CR_LR)
self.train_opt = self.train_opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))
```

so I change the 2nd `self.train_opt` statement to:

```
self.ctrain_op = self.train_opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))
```

**3)** `self.atrain_operation` is an optimizer so I replace this line:

```
self.atrain_operation = self.atrain_operation.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))
```

with:

```
self.atrain_op = self.atrain_operation.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))
```

**4)** Correspondingly, the lines commented out are also replaced in the `update` function:

```
#[self.tfsess.run(self.atrain_operation, {self.tf_state: state, self.tf_action: action, self.tf_advantage: advantage}) for _ in range(ACTOR_UPDATE_STEPS)]
[self.tfsess.run(self.atrain_op, {self.tf_state: state, self.tf_action: action, self.tf_advantage: advantage}) for _ in range(ACTOR_UPDATE_STEPS)]

#[self.tfsess.run(self.train_opt, {self.tf_state: state, self.tf_dreward: reward}) for _ in range(CRITIC_UPDATE_STEPS)]
[self.tfsess.run(self.ctrain_op, {self.tf_state: state, self.tf_dreward: reward}) for _ in range(CRITIC_UPDATE_STEPS)]
```

**5)** In the `tinynn` function, instead of multiplying by a magic number 2:

```
mu = 2 * tf.layers.dense(l1, ACT_DIM, tf.nn.tanh, trainable=trainable)
```

replace it with this:

```
mu = self.env.action_space.high * tf.layers.dense(l1, ACT_DIM, tf.nn.tanh, name='mu', trainable=trainable)
```

**6)** Instead of this `return np.clip(action, -1, 1)` in the `choose_action` function, use this:

```
return np.clip(a, self.env.action_space.low, self.env.action_space.high)
```

**7)** I also pass in `env` to PPO() so that `tinynn` can have access to the environment:

```
"""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ppo = PPO()
    #env = gym.make('RocketLander-v0')
    env = gym.make('Pendulum-v0')
    reward = ppo.train(env, ppo, 100)
    print(reward)
"""    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #env = gym.make('RocketLander-v0')
    env = gym.make('Pendulum-v0')
    ppo = PPO(env)
    reward = ppo.train(env, ppo, 100)
    print(reward)
```

### Results (Tested on Google's Colab):

The output for final `print(reward)` statement **after** fixing the problems **(no more nans)**:

```
[-1076.4211985938728, -1089.7948555704293, -1115.6341917789869, -1147.7961139172062, -1162.9589624975872, -1193.6444573268725, -1214.9662239699737, -1219.295151702447, -1228.3773779343328, -1211.7559065793157, -1239.1770034164979, -1256.5497739717612, -1248.942050034072, -1251.5809026533057, -1246.350714892043, -1223.1414157442061, -1231.5288547710811, -1223.5475405502032, -1217.095971096193, -1215.639878904649, -1182.084416025169, -1174.3085216226718, -1176.5976104186886, -1188.5439312195451, -1160.6565487872776, -1132.5758139546506, -1148.7299082836548, -1149.1097155137375, -1124.4154423538491, -1100.4411098048593, -1081.2445587548245, -1035.7597376533809, -1039.5657416397464, -1046.8627585876952, -1007.554202371864, -997.4072232047926, -924.0742105089892, -872.5268280283873, -889.6594740458157, -929.8577808816676, -957.1616193294444, -887.3960001717214, -811.6005555799227, -769.4648914456843, -692.6909819129986, -623.7238271047137, -656.6829518032941, -629.9657550649539, -651.9125731231816, -678.5172027274579, -683.0097144683796, -640.7089935328387, -589.4306203212271, -556.3242756529115, -526.881331084439, -539.3604006694065, -511.27673189202727, -526.1856726355412, -512.7768642430646, -514.7892695498354, -527.2777710366902, -516.3731318862425, -504.3876365547384, -466.66983741261095, -446.0724507306932, -414.25670263412803, -449.7266236253488, -471.7990471628901, -492.56922815695845, -455.6665136249609, -436.67493361178475, -393.1425637497276, -445.3335873259794, -440.30325932671377, -437.07634044015583, -406.7068409952513, -379.062809279313, -444.46652386541916, -439.60389029825603, -422.0043960746679, -424.80904663279813, -486.0321568909586, -476.00519893661306, -493.3553901668465, -457.4723683354885, -450.83268159600254, -458.6995892890558, -514.3951245072926, -519.3061062950538, -507.1919061966863, -469.59914342990675, -422.66056322913045, -439.53868966691357, -395.9325190449425, -369.7488471733708, -398.1944563259144, -397.3649275140671, -401.18423175784426, -400.9083352836444, -374.0640183220304]
```

### The entire modified code that works (No more nans):

```
import gym
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
#import rocket_lander_gym

EP_LEN = 200
GAMMA = 0.9
SL_LR = 1e-4
CR_LR = 1e-4
BATCH = 5
ACTOR_UPDATE_STEPS = 20
CRITIC_UPDATE_STEPS = 20
#STATE_DIM, ACT_DIM = 10, 3
STATE_DIM, ACT_DIM = 3, 1


METHOD = [
    dict(name='kl_penalty', kl_target=0.01, lam=0.5),   
    dict(name='clip', epsilon=0.2),
][1]

PRINT_DEBUG_MSG = False

class PPO:
    def __init__(self, env):
        self.env = env
        self.tfsess = tf.Session()
        self.tf_state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, STATE_DIM], 'state')

        # Critic (value network)
        with tf.variable_scope('critic'):
            # Layers
            l1 = tf.layers.dense(self.tf_state, 100, tf.nn.relu)
            # Value
            self.value = tf.layers.dense(l1, 1)
            # Discounted reward: reward in the furture
            self.tf_dreward = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], 'discounted_reward')
            # Advantage: determine quality of action
            self.advantage = self.tf_dreward - self.value
            # Loss function: minimize the advantage over time
            # The loss function is a mean squared error
            self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(self.advantage))

            # Gradient descent using Adam optimizer
            self.train_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(CR_LR)
            gradients, variables = zip(*self.train_opt.compute_gradients(self.loss))
            gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, 1.0)

            #self.train_opt = self.train_opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))
            self.ctrain_op = self.train_opt.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))

        # Actor (policy network)
        pi, pi_params = self.tinynn('pi', trainable=True)
        old_pi, old_pi_params = self.tinynn('old_pi', trainable=False)

        # Sample actions from both the old and the new policy networks
        with tf.variable_scope('sample_action'):
            # Choose an action from the distribution learnt
            self.sample_operation = tf.squeeze(pi.sample(1), axis=0)
        with tf.variable_scope('update_old_pi'):
            # Choose an action from the distribution learnt
            self.update_old_pi_operation = [old_pi.assign(p) for p, old_pi in zip(pi_params, old_pi_params)]

        # Placeholder for the action and the advantage
        self.tf_action = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, ACT_DIM], 'action')
        self.tf_advantage = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], 'advantage')

        # Compute loss function
        with tf.variable_scope('loss'):
            with tf.variable_scope('surrogate'):
                #ratio = pi.prob(self.tf_advantage) / old_pi.prob(self.tf_advantage)

                ratio = pi.prob(self.tf_action) / old_pi.prob(self.tf_action)

                surrogate = ratio * self.tf_advantage

            # KL penalty
            if METHOD['name'] == 'kl_penalty':
                # Lambda
                self.tf_lambda = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, None, 'lambda')
                # Compute KL divergence between old and new policy
                kl = tf.contrib.distributions.kl_divergence(old_pi, pi)
                # Get mean
                self.kl_mean = tf.reduce_mean(kl)
                # Compute loss using surrogate
                self.aloss = -(tf.reduce_mean(surrogate - self.tf_lambda * kl))
            else:
                self.aloss = -tf.reduce_mean(tf.minimum(surrogate, tf.clip_by_value(ratio, 1.-METHOD['epsilon'],  1.+METHOD['epsilon']) * self.tf_advantage))

        # Minimize the loss using gradient descent
        with tf.variable_scope('atrain'):
            self.atrain_operation = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(SL_LR)
            gradients, variables = zip(*self.atrain_operation.compute_gradients(self.aloss))
            gradients, _ = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients, 1.0)
            #self.atrain_operation = self.atrain_operation.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))
            self.atrain_op = self.atrain_operation.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, variables))

        # Write to disk
        tf.summary.FileWriter("log/", self.tfsess.graph)

        # Run the session
        self.tfsess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


    def update(self, state, action, reward):
        self.tfsess.run(self.update_old_pi_operation)

        advantage = self.tfsess.run(self.advantage, {self.tf_state: state, self.tf_dreward: reward})

        # Update actor (policy)
        if METHOD['name'] == 'kl_penalty':
            for _ in range(ACTOR_UPDATE_STEPS):
                _, kl = self.tfsess.run([self.atrain_operation, self.kl_mean], {self.tf_state: state, self.tf_action: action, tf_advantage: advantage, self.tf_lambda: METHOD['lam']})
                if kl > 4*METHOD['kl_target']:
                    break
            if kl < METHOD['kl_target'] / 1.5:
                # Adaptive lambda
                METHOD['lam'] /= 2
            elif kl > METHOD['kl_target'] * 1.5:
                METHOD['lam'] *= 2
            # Lambda might explode, we need to clip it
            METHOD['lam'] = np.clip(METHOD['lam'], 1e-4, 10)
        else:
            #[self.tfsess.run(self.atrain_operation, {self.tf_state: state, self.tf_action: action, self.tf_advantage: advantage}) for _ in range(ACTOR_UPDATE_STEPS)]
            [self.tfsess.run(self.atrain_op, {self.tf_state: state, self.tf_action: action, self.tf_advantage: advantage}) for _ in range(ACTOR_UPDATE_STEPS)]

        # Update critic (value)
        #[self.tfsess.run(self.train_opt, {self.tf_state: state, self.tf_dreward: reward}) for _ in range(CRITIC_UPDATE_STEPS)]
        [self.tfsess.run(self.ctrain_op, {self.tf_state: state, self.tf_dreward: reward}) for _ in range(CRITIC_UPDATE_STEPS)]

    def tinynn(self, name, trainable):
        with tf.variable_scope(name):
            l1 = tf.layers.dense(self.tf_state, 100, tf.nn.relu, trainable=trainable)
            #mu = 2 * tf.layers.dense(l1, ACT_DIM, tf.nn.tanh, trainable=trainable)
            mu = self.env.action_space.high * tf.layers.dense(l1, ACT_DIM, tf.nn.tanh, name='mu', trainable=trainable)
            sigma = tf.layers.dense(l1, ACT_DIM, tf.nn.softplus, trainable=trainable)
            norm_dist = tf.distributions.Normal(loc=mu, scale=sigma)
        params = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES, scope=name)
        return norm_dist, params


    def choose_action(self, state):
        state = state[np.newaxis, :]
        action = self.tfsess.run(self.sample_operation, {self.tf_state: state})[0]
        #return np.clip(action, -1, 1)
        return np.clip(action, self.env.action_space.low, self.env.action_space.high)

    def get_value(self, state):
        if state.ndim < 2: state = state[np.newaxis, :]
        return self.tfsess.run(self.value, {self.tf_state: state})[0, 0]


    def train(self, env, ppo, epochs, render=False):
        # Rewards
        all_ep_r = []
        # Training loop
        for ep in range(epochs):
            # Initial state
            s = env.reset()
            # States, actions and rewards
            buffer_s, buffer_a, buffer_r = [], [], []
            # Initial reward
            ep_r = 0
            # For a single episode
            for t in range(EP_LEN):
                if render:
                    # Render the environment
                    env.render()
                # Choose best action
                a = ppo.choose_action(s)
                # State,reward,done,info
                s_, r, done, _ = env.step(a)
                if PRINT_DEBUG_MSG:
                    print("Action Taken  ",a)
                    print("Observation   ",s_)
                    print("Reward Gained ",r, end='\n\n')
                # Add to buffers
                buffer_s.append(s)
                buffer_a.append(a)
                buffer_r.append((r+8)/8)    # normalize reward, find to be useful
                s = s_
                # Total reward
                ep_r += r

                # Update PPO
                if (t+1) % BATCH == 0 or t == EP_LEN - 1:
                    # Get value
                    v_s_ = ppo.get_value(s_)

                    # Discounted reward
                    discounted_r = []
                    # Update rewards
                    for r in buffer_r[::-1]:
                        v_s_ = r + GAMMA * v_s_
                        discounted_r.append(v_s_)
                    discounted_r.reverse()

                    # Buffer states actions rewards
                    bs, ba, br = np.vstack(buffer_s), np.vstack(buffer_a), np.array(discounted_r)[:, np.newaxis]
                    buffer_s, buffer_a, buffer_r = [], [], []
                    ppo.update(bs, ba, br)

                # Check if done
                if done:
                    #print("Simulation done.")
                    break
            # Append episode rewards
            if ep == 0: all_ep_r.append(ep_r)
            else: all_ep_r.append(all_ep_r[-1]*0.9 + ep_r*0.1)
            # Close the environment
            env.close()
        # Return all episode rewards
        return all_ep_r

"""
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ppo = PPO()
    #env = gym.make('RocketLander-v0')
    env = gym.make('Pendulum-v0')
    reward = ppo.train(env, ppo, 100)
    print(reward)
"""    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #env = gym.make('RocketLander-v0')
    env = gym.make('Pendulum-v0')
    ppo = PPO(env)
    reward = ppo.train(env, ppo, 100)
    print(reward)
```